# C++ program to check IBAN account number - How can I set values for each character: A=>10, B=>11, C=>12

Tags: c++

I want to create a C++ program to check IBAN account number.

I'm new in C++ and I need help, I don't know how can I set for each character a value, for example: for A assign 10, for B assign 11 ...

In PHP I made this, because there I used Associative arrays and I used foreach loop, but in C++ I don't have any idea.

I have this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
std::string str,new_str;

getline(std::cin,str);
str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '), str.end());

for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < str.length(); i++ )
    str[i] = toupper(str[i]);

new_str = str;

for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    new_str += str[i];

new_str = new_str.erase(0,4);

std::cout << new_str;

return 0;
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: If you know how to solve it with an associative container, [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) should help.

Answer (score 1):

In c++ you have `map` - like an associative array. Here is an example of usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<char, int> m;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        m['A' + i] = 10 + i;
    }


    // now print it
    for (auto pair : m) {
        cout << pair.first << ": " << pair.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
A: 10
B: 11
C: 12
D: 13
E: 14
F: 15
G: 16
H: 17
I: 18
J: 19
```

Comment: Note that `'A' + i` is not fully portable (as for [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC))